# TimeZone change not reflected in SQLite without restart

Tags: database, sqlite, time, timezone

When the user **switches between timezones** (e.g. travelling), the SQLite local timestamp does not change when I call `strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%f", "now", "localtime")` and the **program is running** during the timezone shift.

When I restart the application, it works well (i.e. the right localized time is used).

Is there some kind of caching in place or a better solution rather than re-connecting?
(I know from C# that I need to [clear the cache](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo.clearcacheddata(v=vs.110).aspx).)

Comment: SQLite just asks the OS. Apparently, your OS (whatever it is) does not tell running programs about the change.

Comment: I am using Windows 10. The time on the OS clock changes immediately after the timezone change; also the time I get from C# (from where I call the SQLite Query).

Comment: SQLite uses the [localtime() function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bf12f0hc.aspx).